# When creating content: Force the checkbox "Provide a menu link" to be checked by default

Tags: 7, routes, forms

When creating content, I would like to force the checkbox "Provide a menu link" to be checked by default.

What I'm really trying to do:

- I created a new content type
- I used `node_add` to get the form associated to my content type and render it into my template.
- In my module I used the `hook_form_alter` to hide some fields of my form.

But when the user submit the form and the node is created, there is no menu link created by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

To force the creation of a menu link I used the hook function [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7):

```
function *MODULE*_node_insert($node){
        if($node->type == '*CONTENT TYPE*'){
            $node->menu['enabled'] = true;
            $node->menu['link_title'] = $node->title;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked everywhere for this! The [Menu Force module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_force) does this:

> This module enables you to make the Menu Settings required on specific content types.

After installing a *"Make the Menu Settings mandatory for this content type"* tick box becomes available on the settings for each content type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hook_form_alter` to set the `#default_value` of the *Provide a menu link* checkbox to `true`.

Comment: There is no "Provide a menu link" item in the "$form" object of "hook_form_alter".

Answer (score -1):

Simple install https://www.drupal.org/project/default_menu_link and there you go.

There is a similar module called [Menu Force](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_force) that does just that. Whereas Menu Force mandates menu assignment, Default Menu Link merely changes the status of "Provide a Menu Link" to true. The user can still create content and choose to un-check this box. However, the default state (on node creation) will be true, and as long as you've set a default menu parent item, all content will be filed under that parent.